# Azure function insert/read from cosmosdb table

Tags: c#, function, azure

I want to read and write to a table from a cosmosdb using azure function on .NET, this code try to read from `Test Table` using `ExecuteQuerySegmentAsync` but it doesn't work.

Its almost working, its writing logs in a new table that it has created. I changed from `TestTable` to `LogTable`, and it successfully retrieved some entities, I tried to manually add a new entity to the log table and it this code is only retrieving the log entities, but I couldn't see anything different from the to the entity I added, I'm lost.

```
public static class HttpTrigger {
    [FunctionName("HttpTrigger")]
    public static HttpResponseMessage Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = null)]HttpRequest req,
        [Table("TestTable")] CloudTable tab,
        TraceWriter log) {
        log.Info("Kicking off.");
        // Load data from TableStorage using CloudTable
        var querySegment = tab.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(new TableQuery(), null);
        //StringContent responseContent = null;

        foreach (DynamicTableEntity item in querySegment.Result) {
            log.Info($"Data loaded: '{item.PartitionKey}'");// | '{item.Familia}' | '{item.IsDeleted}'");
            //responseContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        }

        log.Info("Done.");
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) {
            Content = responseContent
        };
    }
}
```

[**EDIT**]
I discovered that it is reading data from a Table Storage, and i need to read from cosmosDB Table

Comment: I test with your code and work fine, and could read the added entities. So did you confused about jsonconvert.serializeobject?

Comment: My local.settings.json:
`{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"

} }`

Is something missing?

Comment: You need to set `AzureWebJobsStorage` as your storage account connectionstring, where you table is.